# Ошибка celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task ...: send_course_update_email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'course_id'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, celerybeat

У меня есть задача в Django rest framework, она выглядит следующим образом:

```
@shared_task(name='send_message_subscriptions')
def send_course_update_email(course_id):
    # Список подписчиков на обновления курса
    subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(course=course_id)

    # Объект курса
    course = Course.objects.get(pk=course_id)

    # Отправка письма подписчику
    for subscription in subscriptions:
        send_mail(
            subject=f"Курс {course.name} обновлен",
            message=f"Здравствуйте, {subscription.user.username}.\nКурс {course.name} был обновлен. Переходите на "
                    f"сайт, чтобы"
                    f"прочитать новый материал.",
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            recipient_list=[subscription.user.email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        print(send_mail)


def notify_course_subscribers(course_id):
    print(course_id)
    send_course_update_email.delay(course_id)
```

При запуске через админку этой зарегистрированной задачи у меня ошибка:

> check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
> celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task Задача_2: send_course_update_email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'course_id'
> [2023-09-19 13:32:03,733: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Задача_1 (main.tasks.notify_course_subscribers)

worker и beat запущены и исправно работают. Сама модель подписки выглядит следующим образом:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    """Модель Subscription"""
    INSTALL = 'install'
    DELETE = 'delete'

    SUBSCRIPT = [
        (INSTALL, 'у пользователя есть подписка на курс'),
        (DELETE, 'у пользователя отсутствует подписка на курс'),
    ]

    UPDATES_USER = 'update_user'
    NOT_UPDAT_USER = 'not_updat_user'

    UPDATES = [
        (UPDATES_USER, 'пользователь подписан на обновления'),
        (NOT_UPDAT_USER, 'пользователь  не подписан на обновления'),
    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='пользователь')
    updates = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=UPDATES, verbose_name='признак обновление')
    subscription = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SUBSCRIPT, verbose_name='признак подписки')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='курс')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} ({self.subscription})'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Подписка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Подписки'
```

Пробовал вызывать notify_course_subscribers как задачу через админку, и ошибок никаких не было, но задача не выполнялась, так как на email не приходило письмо, вместе с этим email тоже проверен